# permission problems on /run/user/0

Tags: systemd

Our monitoring system user sudo to run some local checks as root. However on the Rocky 8 hosts there are two errors in '/var/log/secure':

```
sudo[2562876]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Failed to stat() runtime directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
sudo[2562876]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Not setting $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, as the directory is not in order.
```

Output from the command is as expected no issues there.
We like to get rid of these messages cause they are polluting our logging system.

We run the checks with 'Defaults:icinga !requiretty' (icinga is the localuser)

We tried to run with !pam_session which gave the same result.
Q: Is there a correct way to suppress these messages?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/run/user`? Are there any SELinux denials logged?

Comment: permissions are drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 80  8 jul 13:33 /run/user/. The problem only exits with the sudo from the monitoring app.